# How to use an array data in node js from a javascript file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have some data stored in an array in javascript and want to use that array in node js. I tried this:

JS:

```
let myArray = ['data1', 'data2'];
```

Node js:

```
let myArray = require('scripts.js').myArray;
```

But I get `Error: Cannot find module` error.

What should I do?

Comment: You should tell use where 'scripts.js' is on the file system relative to your Node script.

Comment: The node.js file is in root and scripts.js is in public/scripts/scripts.js I think there's no problem in path. @Mark_M

Comment: perhaps you need to [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/my/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) the variable first.

Comment: Then you have to require `'./public/scripts/scripts'`. Or `'./scripts'` if the file was in the root folder. Notice the dot in the front of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the syntax to import a node module:
e.g.

```
const app = require('express')
```

Node is looking for a node module named `script.js`

If you want to require local files you need to use the syntax

```
let myArray = require('./scripts').myArray;
```

No need to put the `.js` on the end require does this for you.  The full details in the documentation are here: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules